# Process Builder won't accept ffmpeg arguments

Tags: java, parsing, ffmpeg, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to open a process (ffmpeg) using the Java ProcessBuilder.
So far so good but I can't really pass any arguments to the process.

The ProcessBuilder just won't use the right arguments.

Here's my code so far:

```
ProcessBuilder builder    = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe", "-i " + this.inputFile.getAbsolutePath(), "-c:v libvpx", "-minrate " + iBitrate + "k", "-maxrate " + iBitrate + "k", "-b:v " + iBitrate + "k", "-c:a libvorbis", this.outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

A sample output I got:

```
Unrecognized option 'i D:\Noneatme\Dokumente\AAAAAAAAAAAA\day.mp4'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

I never said "i" or anything like that, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space after `-i` in the 2nd parameter of the ProcessBuilder constructor, and make `this.inputFile.getAbsolutePath()` the 3rd parameter to the ProcessBuilder constructor.  Don't add it to `"-i"`.  Essentially, make sure each element separated by spaces are their own arguments to the ProcessBuilder constructor.

Comment: Holy mother of god you are awesome, thank you.

`ProcessBuilder builder    = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe", "-i", this.inputFile.getAbsolutePath(), "-c:v", "libvpx", "-minrate", iBitrate + "k", "-maxrate", iBitrate + "k", "-b:v", iBitrate + "k", "-c:a", "libvorbis", this.outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
            `